# Create a VM in a resource group using my own vhd

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

In the classic portal/ASM I could use some simple PowerShell cmdlets to create a VM using my own vhd. Once the variables were set the flow was pretty much Add-AzureVhd > Add-AzureDisk > New-AzureVm.

For the life of me I cannot find any documentation on creating an ARM VM using PowerShell with my own vhd.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Edit: Here is the code I am using.

```
$rgName = "somerg"
$location = "centralus"
$storageName = "somestorage"
$storageType = "Standard_LRS"

$nicname = "client1nic"
$subnet1Name = "Subnet-1"
$vnetName = "somevnet"
$vnetAddressPrefix = "10.0.0.0/16"
$vnetSubnetAddressPrefix = "10.0.0.0/24"

$vmName = "Client1"
$vmSize = "Standard_A2"
$osDiskName = $vmName + "osDisk"

$pip = New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name $nicname -ResourceGroupName $rgName                 -Location $location -AllocationMethod Dynamic
$nic = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $nicname -ResourceGroupName $rgName    -Location $location -SubnetId $vnet.Subnets[0].Id -PublicIpAddressId $pip.Id
$vm = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $vmName -VMSize $vmSize$vm = Add-  AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vm -Id $nic.Id
$osDiskUri = "https://somestorage.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/Client1.vhd"
$vm = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $vm -Name $osDiskName -VhdUri $osDiskUri -  CreateOption attach -Windows

New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location -VM $vm -  Verbose -Debug
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk` has three options when creating an OS disk using the `-CreateOptions` The first is `fromImage` which creates an a machine from a prior image.

There is then `attach` which attaches a preexisting disk, which would be the option you require.

There is also `empty` but I've not found the use case for that as yet!

Anyway, this should do what you need.

```
Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $vm -Name "test" -VhdUri $uri -CreateOption attach -Windows
```

Wrapped into the rest of a [VM Create script](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt603754.aspx)

Comment: I get a new error: ErrorCode: DiskBlobNotFound. The disk is most definitely there. I sysprepped the image in Hyper-V before uploading to the blob.

Comment: Thanks Michael B. That last line of code seemed to work. I failed to export the vhd after I ran sysprep from Hyper-V. Once I did that and re-upload to the blob storage I was able to create the Vm.